# How to get screen height till particular element on screen using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get screen height of my webpage from top of the screen till a particular element's bottom.

For example,
Please see below image:
[image]

In the above image, I need screen height where the block "2" ends.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
var height=$("div2").height();
var requiredValue=$("div2").offset().top+height;
```

The first line gives the height of your div and second line adds this height to the position till the window is scrolled.